# Customizing Activities (To-dos) in Odoo 11 CE

Tags: customization, odoo-11

I cannot find a detailed documentation that talks about this aspect of customizing activities (To-dos) in Odoo 11 CE. I managed to programmatically (i.e. in Python) create new activities, associate them to a specific model instance, and assign them to a particular user.

But I still need to customize them further, and here are my questions:

When an activity appears in the activities menu (i.e. in the top bar of Odoo), it shows an icon, title, and few stats (i.e. number of Late, Today, and Future activities).

1. How can I customize the icon?
2. How can I customize the title?
3. How can I customize the stats?
4. How can I group the the activities based on some field in the model instances? (This will allow me to give different custom icons, titles, and stats to different groups, and also open different custom views upon clicking the groups)

When an activity is clicked, the default view of the associated model is opened; how can I open a custom view?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your questions lead you to a non-existing activities/to-do features in Odoo. To be able to get it done you would need to extend it and customize it by yourself with a deep knowledge of Odoo internals and somehow re-make the activities widget and templates in the mail module